# Factorial, tens and units

Tags: c++

Hi guys I'm trying to write a program which will calculate factorial of passed number and show his number of tens and units. This exercise is from spoj.com but apparently my code is too slow and spoj's compiler says I exceed the limit of time.. :/ Any ideas how to speed this code up? :) I've added some comments trying to simplify you understanding of my code. #UPDATE. I reorganized my code and it works also fine but is much shorter ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int tests, number, result = 1, units, tens, auxiliary;

//PROGRAM IS CALCULATING FACTORIAL AND WRITING OUT THE NUMBER OF TENS AND UNITS
int main()
{
cin >> tests; // number of integers you want to check, for example if you cin >> 5 then you have 5 numbers to check the answer
for (int i = 0; i < tests;i++) // imputation of integers to tables
{
    cin >> number;
    result = 1;
    auxiliary = number;
    for(int i=0;i<auxiliary;i++)
    {
        result = result * number;
        number -= 1;
    }
    units = result % 10;   // here I calculate units
    tens = result % 100;  // here I calculate number of tens
    tens = (tens - units) / 10; // here I calculate number of tens #2
    cout << tens <<" "<< units << endl; // here I write out the answer which has the form "x y" <---- "tens units"
    tens = 0;
    units = 0;

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a great practice to use proper variable names and especially **not** one-lettered names.

Comment: I think that name variables not in English, makes reading your code unnecessarily hard...

Comment: I feel like the `cin>>` causes too much latency.

Comment: I will edit it and make it English names, sorry

Comment: Do you have to use dynamic arrays and `new`? Is there any limitations on any library?

Comment: If your code "works", but simply isn't efficient enough to pass the time-limits of spij, wouldnt [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) be a more appropraite place for this?

Comment: It is said in my exercise that tests (1<tests<30), I mean that this site will test it not only for one example but couple of them and I thought that using dynamic tables would increase the speed of the program

Comment: Just use `std::vector` instead, for a cleaner and better code

Comment: I can assure you the two upfront, single-hit allocations of two arrays is *not* the sore point of your algorithm.

Comment: Also you need to show us a sample input, and its desired output. Because what do you mean by `units` and `tens`? And why the 5 inputs?

Comment: First the program ask you to write how many factorials do you want to check, I say for example I want to check 3 factorials SO I write in 3 and click enter. then its my first out of 3 example so i write in number e.g 4 (4! == 24) and  it counts factorial then i put in second factorial I want to check e.g 6 (6!  == 720) Then third factorial e.g 7 (7! == 5040) The output is: 
2 4 (endl;)
2 0 (endl;)
4 0 (endl;)

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, let's assume you want to actually calculate a meaningful result, not just pre-calculate the few results that vary, and store a single, fixed result for all other inputs.

If you're doing the calculation, you're dealing with modular arithmetic. That is, you're doing `A * B * C ... mod M`, for some set of (integer) inputs. What we can observe about this is that the modulus part of that is distributable. For example, if any of the inputs might be greater than our modulus (M), we can change:

```
A * B mod M
```

into:

```
((A mod M) * (B mod M) mod M)
```

...and still get the same result. We can also do the same thing with all our intermediate results, so for some arbitrary number of inputs:

```
A * B * C * D * E [...] mod M
```

can become:

```
intermediate = A mod M;
for (V in A, B, D, E [...])
    intermediate *= V mod M;
    intermediate = intermediate mod M;
```

...and still get the same result.

This means the largest number we ever have to deal with is approximately M<sup>2</sup>. In your case, M = 100, so we never have to represent any number large than 10000. That means it will always fit into an `int` (since it's guaranteed to support at least 16-bit numbers.

Taking advantage of modular arithmetic this way, we can do the multiplication *much* more quickly. More interestingly, this basic technique extends to quite a few more interesting cases than just this one (e.g., it's used on a regular basis in implementing RSA encryption/decryption).

Comment: I don't get what you're saying :c Is it possible for you to explain this whole  thing but based on my code? I mean if you would like to change/add couple of lines to my code, it would made much easier to understand it for me? Please :)

Comment: Sorry, but the closest I'm going to go is pseudo-code. But if you do some looking at how RSA is implemented, it might give some more ideas though.

Comment: He's using an int as his intermediate, so he's already doing this as much as possible. Though I'm not sure he intended to.

Comment: @patstew: he sort of is, but given that it's using the wrong modulus, he's not doing it very well. OTOH, using the right modulus might not help with speed either.

Comment: Yes, I meant in terms of speeding it up. He hasn't asked about getting the wrong answer for numbers > 20 or so :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the first 20 factorials:

```
1
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
6227020800
87178291200
1307674368000
20922789888000
355687428096000
6402373705728000
121645100408832000
2432902008176640000
```

You don't actually need to calculate the factorial for any number greater than 10, because your answer is always 0, 0. And for the other 10 you may as well just print the results from an array.

Comment: umm, ok, but this site (spoj) won't accept this ;d I mean I checked this program and it works fine, but it is too slow :c